# iPad apps transferring to iPhone through iCloud

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, icloud

If I download any app on my iPad will it download itself to my iPhone? The iPhone & iPad share the same iCloud account.

Answer (score 4):

In settings->Itunes & App Stores you can choose whether to enable automatic downloads for apps purchased on other devices.

Assuming the app is compatible on both this means if you turn it on for Apps on your phone, then it will download itself to the phone after purchasing on the iPad.

Answer (score -1):

Your apple ID is Designed to synchronize all of your Devices together your Apple ID was meant for one person and one person only. You shouldn't really share your Apple ID with Anyone because it is supposed personalized for you only.